# How to touch multiple files, each with unique filenames, files to be created from outside the current directory. Using Git Bash CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, git-bash

This touch example creates multiple files in the current working directory:

```
touch register.ejs secret.ejs
```

How do we achieve the same result when we are outside the current working directory?
I tried this example but the second file does not get created:

```
$ touch views/register.ejs secret.ejs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddled around and got it. If there is a shorter way without repeating the file path please advise. Thx

```
touch views/register.ejs & touch views/secret.ejs
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I've just found out you can do this:

touch sub_dir1/sub_dir2/{file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt}

See [this article](https://trendoceans.com/create-multiple-files-and-directories/#Creating_Multiple_Files_at_Once) for more info.